# Python: Replace data from one dataframe using other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to replace data from df1 using dataframe df2 based on column A

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 0, 4],'B': [5, 6, 7, 5, 9],'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e'],'E': ['a1', '1b', '1c', '1a', '1e']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1],'B': ['new', 'new1'],'C': ['t', 't1']})
```

Comment: What is expected output, how looks DataFrame from sample data?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, replace missing values by original DataFrame by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and last filter columns by `df1.columns`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='left', suffixes=('_','')).fillna(df1)[df1.columns]
print(df)
   A     B   C   E
0  0   new   t  a1
1  1  new1  t1  1b
2  2     7   c  1c
3  0   new   t  1a
4  4     9   e  1e
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option.

```
##set index to be the same
df1 = df1.set_index('A')
df2 = df2.set_index('A')

##update df1
df1.loc[df2.index,df2.columns] = df2

##reset the index to get it back to a column
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```